# What is this game: An adventure/combat PC game played in the sky, on large weird airships you could upgrade as the story advanced

Tags: pc, game-identification

The game was a 3D Adventure/combat game on airships in the sky.

Released before 2011.

Notable referenced characters: "Master builder"

Description: You were on some kind of large airships and would be able to upgrade them as the story advanced. There was combat between ships.

I have kept a sound file that said the following:

"In the first light of day they set off for the cloud gate, the only entrance to the second level. No one had traveled between the levels for innumerable years. The old master builder seemed satisfied, and his friend's rescue drew one step nearer."

I know it is very thin information, but this has been bugging me for weeks now ...

[Here is a link to the sound file on dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pfap6yybumcukwc/SP_ADPCM_M_16.wav?dl=0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [Project Nomads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Nomads), a 2002 PC game by Radon Labs.

Here is clip of that audio in the game: